# Execute JavaScript pop up box from java code

Tags: javascript, java, html, rest

I would like to have this scenario where if a method is being called, the code inside the method will be able to call a JavaScript method to display a pop up box in the web page.

I read something about script engine but am not sure if it works in this kind of scenario.
Or do i need to use Observer Pattern (e.g. web socket) to listen for any events?

```
    // -------------------Create a Report-------------------------------------------
//This method is being called. 
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @RequestMapping(value = "/proposal/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
                public ResponseEntity<?> createReport(@RequestBody Report report, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
                    logger.info("Creating Report : {}", report);

                    if (reportRepository.isReportExist(report)) {
                        logger.error("Unable to create. A report with name {} already exist", report.getCrisisID());
                        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("Unable to create. A Report with crisisID " + 
                        report.getCrisisID() + " already exist."),HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
                    }
                    reportRepository.saveReport(report);

                    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/CMOtoPMO/proposal/{crisisID}").buildAndExpand(report.getCrisisID()).toUri());

//Code will call the javascript function to call show a pop up/alert box in my webpage

                    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

To call `JavaScript`, you can use `javax.script`

```
import javax.script.*;
...
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
...
engine.eval(...);
```

More information found [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-javaee/index.html)